# Kotlin Recycler View with Multiple View - alternative Swipe to ability

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, calendar

I am using RecyclerView.ViewHolder to display different layouts in a recyclerview to display the below layout. Also using a Adapter to achieve this. -But I would also like to add a Swipe to Delete on the CardView (Event) of the below image and not the view of the time between events. Is this possible and any suggested approaches please?
[image]

Comment: show the adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Item touch helper will help you to achieve the above.

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouch=new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        //delete item in list
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```